# Autogenerated outlet from Xcode to Visual Studio changes to NSObject

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio

The type of outlets created in the Xcode changes to `Foundation.NSObject`.

I have some custom subclass as "RoundedButton", "BlackBox" or even when I use `NSTextField` or `NSBox` it is getting changed in Visual Studio to `Foundation.NSObject`.

I am not sure whether it started happening when I update to VS for mac 8.7.

Or something is changed in the project.

Any help is appreciated.